# I finalized Oracle Cloud Always Free Boot Volumes

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm using a Free-Tier VM instance.

I deleted and finalized 2 Boot Volumes(tagged Always Free).

And create new 2 Boot Volumes.

I can't see the tags written 'Always Free'

Will I be charged for the two newly created Boot Volumes after the free trial expires?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Technically unless you upgrade to paid account, all non free product will be terminated once the trial expire. You can also check Cost analysis on account management page to check if they're incuring cost

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible your total block volume use exceeds these limits?

- 100 GB total of combined boot volume and block volume Always Free
  Block Volume storage.
- Five total volume backups (boot volume and
  block volume combined).

Detailed limits are in [this documentation](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/FreeTier/resourceref.htm).

Answer (score 0):

> Will I be charged for the two newly created Boot Volumes after the
> free trial expires?

As long as your usage is restricted to Always-Free resources, you should be able to use them for unlimited period of time. Please review the documentation for additional information.

Answer (score -1):

I solved.

I delete all resources. and create again. it works. new instances and volumes are all have the tags 'Always Free'.